draw a plane in Asymptote, based on its normal equation
Is there a built-in way to draw a plane in asymptote, based on its normal equation?
You can draw circles like this, using the path3 mycircle = circle(c=circleCenter, r=1, normal=Y+Z);, as on page 60 of the tutorial.
Here is an MWE of doing it the "Cartesian" way:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(2cm);
import three;
import graph3;
currentprojection = orthographic(1,1,1);

// Plane: 1.5x + y - z = 2
triple myplane(pair uv) {
    return (
        uv.x
        ,uv.y
        ,1.5uv.x + uv.y -2
    );
}

surface theplane = surface(myplane, (-5,-5), (5,5), Spline);
draw(theplane, surfacepen=material(white, emissivepen=0.2 white));
\end{asy}
\end{document}


